# AS3: Fullscreen button when SWF is embedded in HTML

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen

This is the callback function for my fullscreen button. It works if you play the SWF in a standalone player, but it doesn't do anything if it's embedded in an HTML.

```
var isFS:Boolean;
function toggleFS(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    isFS = !isFS;
    if (isFS) {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    } else {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    }
}
```

In the Flash Pro CS6 publish settings, I have the HTML wrapper Template setting on "Flash Only - Allow Full Screen". The HTML has the following code which should allow the SWF to go fullscreen:

```
<object ...>
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
```

I've tested it in Firefox, Chrome, and IE, and the fullscreen button won't work in any of those. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, the HTML needs `<param name="allowFullScreenInteractive" value="true" />` instead to make it work with full keyboard input.